# Regex for adding a dial code to a phone number

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Hey I am beginner with regexs and I am not able to figure this out. What is the regular expression that adds the dial code (420) to phone number("tel" state variable here) if missing/adds plus character if missing/if there are 12 numbers already, turn the three first into dial code. Here are the desired outputs:

123456789 --> +420 123 456 789

(+420) 12 34567 89 --> +420 123 456 789

+420-123456789 --> +420 123 456 789

+987123456789 --> +987 123 456 789

420123456789 --> +420 123 456 789

```
import React, { useContext, useState, useEffect } from "react";
import DataContext from "../store/data-context";


function Form() {
  const [name, setName] = useState("");
  const [secName, setSecName] = useState("");
  const [tel, setTel] = useState("");
  const [note, setNote] = useState("");
  const [state, setState] = useState({
    name: "",
    secName: "",
    tel: "",
    note: "",
  });
  

  const { dispatchDataState } = useContext(DataContext);

  const handleSubmit = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    console.log(name);
    
    const payload={...state, tel:  state.tel.replace(/[^+\d]+/g, "").split('').reverse().join('').replace(/([0-9]{3})/g, "$1 ").split('').reverse().join('')}
    console.log(state)
    console.log(tel)
    dispatchDataState({ type: "ADD_DATA", payload:payload});
    setState(
      {
        name: "",
        secName: "",
        tel: "",
        note: "",
      }
    )
    console.log(state);
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
        <label>
          Jméno
          <input
            type="text"
            required
            value={state.name}
            onChange={(e) => setState({ ... state, name: e.target.value })}
          />
        </label>
        <label>
          Příjmení
          <input
            type="text"
            required
            value={state.secName}
            onChange={(e) => setState({ ... state, secName: e.target.value })}
          />
        </label>
        <label>
          Telefonní číslo
          <input
            type="text"
            required
            value={state.tel}
            onChange={(e) => setState({ ... state, tel: e.target.value })}
            
          />
        </label>
        <label>
          Poznámka
          <input
            type="text"
            value={state.note}
            onChange={(e) => setState({ ... state, note: e.target.value })}
          />
        </label>
        <input type="submit" value="Odeslat" />
      </form>
    </div>
  );
}

export default Form;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [intl-tel-input](https://www.npmjs.com/package/intl-tel-input) package for this feature instead of implementing logic by yourself.

It's a popular zero-dependency package that has:

- dial code prefix for each country
- flag image for each country
- optional validation for user inputs